# IE textarea width changes when user types some text

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textarea

I have a page in which there are a few textarea and <input type="text"> html controls. These elements are placed in a div tag:

[image]

In IE 7 after the user types some text in textarea, the width of the textarea changes on its own:
[image]

and now again if the user types some text in the textbox, the textarea agian returns to its original width:
[image]

Has anyone faced any similar issues?

Comment: Do you have some code we could look at? I'm not sure we can solve this without some HTML/JS/CSS

Comment: thanks for the question. i have come across the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a width in px, for the textfields.
Should resolve the expanding behaviour.

Comment: wish there was a better way though. it works but... ahhhh the aggravation, making things work in ie6

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently facing the same problem on IE8 and IE9. In my case, the text area, expands to full width of window when I type in it. When the focus shifts to any other component, it comes back to original width. Upon enough reading and trying a couple of things, my observation is, if we wrap text area with a `fieldset` tag, width comes to control. But, currently upon trying it, width seems to come to proper width BUT as initially the DOM loads, the textarea seems to have reduced width, then it expands to proper width. Minor though but it still is a bug in my application and I'm unable to understand this behavior. Any help is appreciated.

This is what currently (partially) works for me:

```
<fieldset>

<textarea> </textarea>

</fieldset>
```